# Recursive type or function dependency context too complex

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I am currently doing some C++ project involving a class template. I wanted to create a recursive function, using the template value but I the compiler (Visual Studio 2015) returned me an error : "C1202 : recursive type or function dependency context too complex"

Here is the incriminated function :

```
template<unsigned int Size>
double Matrice<Size>::determinant()
{
    switch (Size)
    {
    case 2: return data[0] * data[3] - data[1] * data[2];
    case 3: return data[0] * (data[4] * data[8] - data[5] * data[7])
        - data[1] * (data[3] * data[8] - data[5] * data[6])
        + data[2] * (data[3] * data[7] - data[4] * data[6]);
    default:
        double sum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < Size; k++)
        {
            sum += (1 - 2 * (k % 2)) * get(0, k) * subMat(0, k).determinant(); //alterner 1 et -1 : (-1)^n = 1-2*(n%2)
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the return type of `subMat(0,k)`?  In particular, I think it needs to be `Matrice<Size-1>` and a special case that it doesn't exist for `Size`==1.  Don't you need a `case 1: return data[0];` (and possibly a `case 0: return 0.;`?  (You may know that you never use size zero matrices - it's not so obvious the compiler can tell that.)

Comment: I guess `subMat(0,0)` indeed returns a zero sized matrix, isnt it?

Comment: Template generate its code at compile time, (1 - 2 * (k % 2)) * get(0, k) * subMat(0, k) calculates at run time, either variables should be constrexpr. Take a look at GNU GSL matrix implementation

Comment: Well the problem was indeed there, thanks a lot for your help. I'm working on it based on your recommandations :)

Comment: implement fair calculation without hardcode. I would add function which take an element and matrice and return calculations with element: element(0.0)*element(1.1)*...*element(n-1,n-1) and element(0,0)*element(1,n-1)*element(2,n-1)*...*element(n-1, 1) also coefficient (-1)^(i+j), well simple linear algebra